# Initialize a matrix with condition

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm new in MATLAB and I need help. I have to complete a code that initializes a matrix, but I don't know where to start.

The matrix must be in this form: 
[image]

Where `Yi = i/m` for `i = 1, ..., m`, with `m=6`.

The code to complete is:

```
m = 6;
A = [1:m;
     1:m;
     ...];

A = A/m;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/).

```
m = 6;
A = ((1:m).'/m).^(0:m);
```

Explanation. First make a column vector with the values `y1` till `ym`.

```
c = (1:m).'/6;
```

Then make a matrix, in which the first column will be `c` to the power of 0, the second `c` to the power of 1, etc.

You can do this easily with implicit expansion, take your column vector and raise to the power (element wise) of the row vector containing `0:m`.

```
A = c.^(0:m);
```

Comment: nice solution by using implicit expansion, +1

Comment: Also `[ones(m,1) cumprod(repmat((1:m).'/m, 1, m), 2)]`

Answer (score 2):

Here are two approaches:

- use `vander` + `fliplr`

```
A = fliplr(vander((1:m)/m));
```

- use `arrayfun` + `vertcat`

```
C = arrayfun(@(x) x.^(0:m),(1:m)/m, 'UniformOutput', false);
A = vertcat(C{:});
```

**Result**

```
>> A
A =

   1.000000000   0.166666667   0.027777778   0.004629630   0.000771605   0.000128601   0.000021433
   1.000000000   0.333333333   0.111111111   0.037037037   0.012345679   0.004115226   0.001371742
   1.000000000   0.500000000   0.250000000   0.125000000   0.062500000   0.031250000   0.015625000
   1.000000000   0.666666667   0.444444444   0.296296296   0.197530864   0.131687243   0.087791495
   1.000000000   0.833333333   0.694444444   0.578703704   0.482253086   0.401877572   0.334897977
   1.000000000   1.000000000   1.000000000   1.000000000   1.000000000   1.000000000   1.000000000
```